# Portable AC isn't dispensing water to the water tank

Tags: plumbing, hvac, air-conditioning, leak, portable-ac

It was leaking at the bottom instead draining water to the intended reservoir. I plugged a tube (labeled "idle tube", greenish looking one) on the water tank area image and now water is filling that tube.

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

How do I make it dispense water back to the tank?

Comment: Did it just start doing this or has it been leaking all along?

Comment: Just 3 days ago, for the last 8 years it has been fine

Comment: It looks like one of the straps is disconnected. Wy ?

Comment: Why are the cable straps loosened?  What does the instructions tell you to do?  It sounds like you acquired a unit that's been tampered with.  Well, that's good then - time to get a vastly more efficient window unit or 2-hose unit.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc

Comment: 8-year-old vinyl tubing. It could simply be failing. Have you disconnected the tubing and looked for cracks? Is it stiff or still soft and pliable? If you're not up for a full on replacement unit (with better efficiency), it might simply be time to replace all the tubing.

Comment: This is a good question and I hope you get a good answer but I want to add that I've had my share of similar problems and with an 8 year old machine, your time and effort is better spent on replacing it.

Comment: I bought it new, I never tampered with the tubes until now. Also the Idle tube was disconnected before, I connected it myself because now the water drops from that exit